# MDX query to group by date period by parameter with number of days

Tags: mdx

We need in a MDX query to group by Date column by number of days from parameter.
Example:

```
Date       Requestor  Duration  Duration RFC
-------    --------   -------   -------
1/1/2011    C1         100      150
1/15/2011   C1         200      250
2/1/2011    C1         300      350
2/1/2011    C2         400      450
```

Parameter Days=30 Begin =1/1/2011
Result:

```
Period                Requestor  Duration  Duration RFC
----                  --------   -------   -------
1/1/2011-1/30/2011     C1         300      400
1/31/2011-2/2/2011     C1         300      350
1/31/2011-2/2/2011     C2         400      450
```

can somebody help me with MDX query?
Sample MDX query(without grouping I need):

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Close Date].[Year  -  Month -  Date].[Date]*[Requestor].[Requestor].  [Requestor]} ON ROWS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Duration] ,[Measures].[RFC Audit  Stage Count]} ON
COLUMNS FROM (SELECT ( STRTOSET (@CategoryCategory, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( select (STRTOSET(@RequestorRequestor,CONSTRAINED)) ON COLUMNS FROM [RFC Cube]))
```

Using SSAS 2008.
 
Cube Name: RFC Cube.
 Dimensions(with hierarchies): 
1. Date= [Close Date].[Year - Month - Date].[Date] 
2. Customer = [Requestor].[Requestor].[Requestor] 
3. Amount1(Measure) = [Measures].[Duration] 
4. Amount2(Measure) = [Measures].[RFC Audit Stage Count]

Comment: Is this MDX or SQL ? If mdx what are your dimensions, hierarchies, measures and what OLAP vendor are you using ?

Comment: Yes, MDX. Using SSAS 2008.<br/>
Cube Name: RFC Cube.
Dimensions(with hierarchies): 
1. Date= [Close Date].[Year  -  Month -  Date].[Date]
2. Customer = [Requestor].[Requestor].[Requestor]
3. Amount1(Measure) = [Measures].[Duration]
4. Amount2(Measure) = [Measures].[RFC Audit  Stage Count]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the grouping has a static number of members, you can use the `Aggregate` function the create calculated members in an hierarchy of the `Date` dimension.

In your case, however, it seems the grouping is dynamic, which you can't do in MDX; you'll have to create a new attribute in your `Date` (?) dimension.